# Div content alignment - Content larger than container and in wrong place

Tags: html, css

I have two issues, but I will describe them as one since I feel they are related. This is my code (this is relating to the size being viewed +1200px):

http://jsfiddle.net/45Lbvejd/6/embedded/result/

**Issue 1:** The div that holds the search box (.b) is less high than the content inside it. I t should be 46px. I think this is to do with floats.

**Issue 2:** The searchbox should line up vertically with the button on the right and yet the search box sits too low. Again I think this is to do with floats.

This is my markup:

```
<header>
    <div id="a" class="left"> <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>

    </div>
    <div id="b" class="left">
        <input id="keyword" class="testinput" placeholder="Keyword">
    </div>
    <div id="c" class="right"><a href="a.html" class="btnj">A</a>

    </div>
</header>
<div id="d">-</div>
```

Partical CSS:

```
/* Blocks */
 #a, #b, #c, #d {
    padding: 0px 15px;
}
/* Top Blocks */
 #a, #c {
    width: 100px;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
    position: absolute;
}
#a img {
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    display: block;
}
#b {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 46px;
}
#c {
    right: 0;
}
#d {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
}
@media (min-width: 520px) {
    .testinput {
        width: 47%
    }
    #location {
        float: right;
    }
    #keyword {
        float: left;
    }
    #d {
        top: 120px;
    }
    .job .logo {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 840px) {
    #b {
        margin-top:0;
        padding: 15px 100px;
    }
    .testinput {
        width: 320px;
    }
    #d {
        padding: 0px 100px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #d {
        padding: 0px 165px;
    }
    #b {
        padding: 15px 165px;
    }
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this how you'd like it to be? **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/45Lbvejd/9/embedded/result/)**. A lot of `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` was applied to `.b` div using CSS which is why it was getting pushed downwards, out of it's specified height of `46px`. I've removed all that padding and instead used `margin-top: 5px` to vertically align the search-box with the button the right side.

Comment: Thank you for the help. That is correct. Just so I understand though, I'm not applying a 5px top margin to the button and it is the same height as the search box, so why do I need to put a top margin on the search box just to get it to line up?

Comment: My understanding is the line-height is centering the button within the 46px height but not the input box

Comment: @jimmy That is indeed correct. The property of `line-height: 46px` applied to `#c` and the `margin-top: 3px` applied to `.btnj` are the reasons why the button on the right is vertically centered.